Jitsi Websocket issue
I have installed jitsi docker on my system.I have SSL Certificate,LDAP authentication etc.
If I log in as username it works fine but if I log in as username@domain I get the following error
[modules/xmpp/strophe.util.js] <Ia.St.Strophe.log>:  Strophe: WebSocket stream error: host-unknown - This server does not serve  WebSocket stream error: host-unknown - This server does not serve 
If I disable XMPP I get the following error.Any ideas
[modules/xmpp/strophe.util.js] <Ia.St.Strophe.log>:  Strophe: BOSH-Connection failed: improper-addressing BOSH-Connection failed: improper-addressing
